# Yii2 views not receive variable

Tags: php, yii2

I have page A with link :

```
<a href="/b?id=1"></a>
```

with controller `BController.php` like:

...

```
public function actionB(){
         $id = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam("id");
        $model= new TestModel();
        $data = $model->find()->where(["id" => $id])->one();
        return $this->render('b',["data"=>$data]);

}
```

when link in `A` click , it redirect to views `b`
 views `b.php` just display value:

```
<?= $data->field_name?>
```

Now I can not see anything in views ,sure that in controller ,I can get data success

Please help me what wrong

Comment: `getQueryParam("i")` ........ should be `getQueryParam("id")`, I think

Comment: I'm sorry ,just typo mistake ,param get is correct in my source code and I can dump $data variable to see it

Comment: you can try  `$data = TestModel::find()->where(["id" => $id])->one();
        return $this->render('b',["data"=>$data]);`

Comment: `var_dump($data);` Check it contain any data. .

Comment: Any errors?  if you do just `return $this->render('b',["data"=>"Hello world"]);` and in view `<?= $data; ?>` will it show you anything? if  it will,  ---->  query didn't return anything.....what shows `print_r($data)`?

Comment: Thansk ,var_dump and print_r not show anything in views

Comment: That mean `$data` is empty. so you will not get anything to display.

Answer (score 1):

If you want pass id to actionB you should  use

```
public function actionB($id){
     //$id = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam("id");
    $model= new TestModel();
    $data = $model->find()->where(["id" => $id])->one();
    return $this->render('b',["data"=>$data]);

}
```